# Merge two sorted arrays using for loop is missing the last item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, mergesort

I m new to dealing with algorithms and my challenge was to merge two sorted lists into one using for loop not while loop. I got stuck at determining the end of the list:

```
list1=[1,2,4]
list2=[1,3,4,6]

def mergeTwoLists(list1: list, list2:list) -> list:
     l = 0
     r = 0
     lRange = len(list1)-1
     rRange = len(list2)-1

     total_range = (len(list1)+len(list2))-1
     merger = []

     for i in range(total_range):
         
         if list1[l]<=list2[r]:
             
             merger.insert(i,list1[l])
             if l<lRange:
                 l+=1
            
         elif list1[l]>list2[r]:
             
             merger.insert(i,list2[r])
             if r<rRange:            
                 r+=1
     return(merger)
```

It returns [1,1,2,3,4,4] and missing the last value 6.

Comment: Have you considered not subtracting 1 when calculating the range of indices?

Comment: yes but then I get out of index error

Comment: Why are you using `insert()` instead of `append()`?

Comment: @MikeCurtis Fix the index error by checking that `l` and `r` are within range before using them.

Comment: You are trying to run through the two lists at a time but then one out of it runs out of indices. You cannot use `l` and `r`  at a time then. Only time you can use both indices is when both of them are in their limits so rethink about your loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the last element because you subtract 1 when creating `total_range`.

You need to test which index is still within range inside the loop. You can only compare elements while both indexes are in range for their respective lists. Once you reach the end of one of the lists, just copy the rest of the other list to the result.

```
def mergeTwoLists(list1: list, list2:list) -> list:
     l = 0
     r = 0
     lRange = len(list1)
     rRange = len(list2)

     total_range = lRange + rRange
     merger = []

     for i in range(total_range):
         if l < lRange and r < rRange:
             if list1[l]<=list2[r]:
                 merger.append(list1[l])
                 l+=1
             elif list1[l]>list2[r]:
                 merger.append(list2[r])
                 r+=1
         elif l < lRange:
            merger.extend(list1[l:])
            break
         else:
            merger.extend(list2[r:])
            break

     return(merger)

list1=[1,2,4]
list2=[1,3,4,6]
print(mergeTwoLists(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works for different kinds of lists. It gets items from the lists in an asynchronous manner and breaks out of loop when length of any one list is finished. Finally, it appends any excess items from the other list.

```
def mergeSortedLists(l1, l2): 
    outlist =[]; i=0; j=0; 
    while i<len(l1) and j<len(l2):
        a = l1[i]; b = l2[j]
        if a<b: 
            outlist.append(a); i+=1
        else: 
            outlist.append(b); j+=1
    outlist += l1[i:] + l2[j:]
    print(outlist)
```

Try:

```
list1=[1,2,4]
list2=[1,3,4,6,7]
mergeSortedLists(list1, list2)
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7]
```

Or:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6,8]
mergeSortedLists(list1, list2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Might work for this specific example, but will fail as soon as multiple items have to come from the same list.

Comment: It should work. I have added a longer list example.

Comment: Try `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`.

Comment: I have changed my code in answer above. Now it  works.

Comment: Now that you've given up the idea of using `zip`, there's a chance it's correct.